# add code to ajax post form submit

Tags: ajax, jquery

i have the next code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#productfilter").validate({
        submitHandler: function (form) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "listproresult_core.php",
                data: $("#productfilter").serialize(),

                beforeSend: function () {
                    $("#contentincore").html("<img src='../loading_core/loading animated/loader.gif'class='clock' border='0' />");
                },

                success: function (result) {
                    $("#contentincore").html(result);
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

and i wish add the next functions inside and that the results of the form, the links are implemented inside the load function results

```
$('#contentincore a').click(function (e) {
    ("#contentincore").on("click", "a:not(.minlink)", function (e) {
        ("#contentincore").load($(this).attr("href"));
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To bind functions to content that is loaded in with ajax, you have to use `.on()`. Here's a live example: http://jsfiddle.net/GMDah/ (check the console) When pressing the top link, "pressed" will be printed in the console. When the bottom link with class `.minlink` is pressed, the code in here is not executed.

The code being:

```
$("#contentincore a:not(.minlink)").on("click", function (e) {
    console.log("pressed");
});
```

Also, don't forget putting the `$`-sign or `jQuery` before your brackets, you seem to have missed a few.

Comment: can make locating the code example I just sent to me to publish please?

Comment: Somewhere on your page inside the `$(document).ready(function(){ // here `. (So after closing the brackets of `$('..').validate({ ...`